# Save Uploaded Excel file to MongoDB Binary format and Read back Mongodb binary to Excel in SpringBoot Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, apache-poi

Problem Statement:I have to save the uploaded excel xlsx sheet file in to MongoDB Binary Format as one of the property of mongodb collection document, so that later whenever i want, i can hit the db and get/fetch the saved xlsx excel binary file and convert to again my excel using java spring boot?

I tried to convert the uploaded file to byte array and then converted to MongoDb binary and stored as a property of a mongodb collection/document but when retrieving it says stream not supported error